# heroku create -stack cedar : ! Stack not found

Tags: heroku, playframework

I follow the instructions on http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play to get my Play! (Java) app running on heroku.

However, I'm stuck on this step, with the error 'stack not found'.

```
$ heroku create -stack cedar 
! Stack not found
```

Unfortunately the documentation is not very complete, some important information about prerequisites seems to be missing, incl. minimum required ruby version.
What does this error "Stack not found" mean? I thought the toolbelt installation already includes all required prerequisites so far, if not otherwise listed - at least I would assume that from such a Getting Started doc's prerequisites section?

(I'm on Mac OS X Lion, Ruby 1.9.3)

Comment: Clearly this is a confusing error message. But not sure how it should be fixed since "heroku create -scedar" is a perfectly valid syntax today. I opened an issue for it: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/223

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that's not a typo, you need to use `--stack` not `-stack`:

```
$ heroku create --stack cedar
```